# EC2 instances recreated by Terraform when new AMI released

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, devops, amazon-ami

I have written some Terraform code to create some servers. For AMI I was using the Terraform data module to get the latest Ubuntu 16.04 image ID and assign it to the EC2 instances.

Recently I wanted to add another EC2 instance to this environment, however when I run `terraform plan` I can see that Terraform is trying to delete the existing EC2 instance and recreate them. The reason being that a new Ubuntu image has been released and it is trying to delete the old instance and create new ones with the new AMI ID.

Is there any chance I can address this issue as I don't want to accidentally delete our production servers?

```
data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-xenial-16.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }
}

module "jenkins" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/ec2-instance/aws"

  name           = "Jenkins"
  instance_count = 1

  ami                         = "${data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id}"
  instance_type               = "t2.small"
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  disable_api_termination     = true
  key_name                    = "${aws_key_pair.ssh_key.key_name}"
  monitoring                  = false
  vpc_security_group_ids      = "${module.jenkins_http_sg.this_security_group_id}", "${module.jenkins_https_sg.this_security_group_id}", "${module.ssh_sg.this_security_group_id}"]
  subnet_id                   = "${module.vpc.public_subnets[0]}"
  iam_instance_profile        = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.update-dns-profile.name}"

  tags = {
    Terraform       = "true"
  }
}
```

Comment: What does Ansible have to do with this? Do you mean you wrote some Terraform code to create some servers?

Comment: sorry I meant terraform code not Ansible. My mistake.

Answer (score 13):

While the answer above helps, I solved the problem by adding the following to the aws_instance resource.

```
lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = ["ami"]
  }
```

Please note if you are using the AWS module like I am using, you will have to enter this code to the main.tf file in .terraform/modules/.

Comment: @ydaetskcor ‘s answer was helpful and relevant,  but this is the one I was looking for. Just noting that using quotes as above, `[”ami”]`, is now deprecated, just put `[ami]`

Answer (score 5):

Terraform is doing exactly as you asked it to do. Each time it runs it looks for the most recent AMI with a name beginning with `ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-xenial-16.04-amd64-server-*` and then passes that AMI ID to the `aws_instance` resource. As it's not possibly to modify the image ID of an instance, Terraform correctly determines it must destroy the old instances and rebuild them from the new AMI.

If you want to specify a specific AMI then you should either make the data source only return a single AMI (eg by specifying the date stamp in the `name` filter) or you should hardcode the AMI ID you want to use.

```
data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
  most_recent = true
  owners      = ["099720109477"] # Canonical

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-xenial-16.04-amd64-server-20190403"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }
}
```

or:

```
variable "ami" {
  default = "ami-0727f3c2d4b0226d5"
}
```

If you were to remove the `most_recent = true` parameter then instead your data source would find multiple images that match those criteria and then fail as the [`aws_ami` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/ami.html) can only return a single AMI:

> NOTE: If more or less than a single match is returned by the search, Terraform will fail. Ensure that your search is specific enough to return a single AMI ID only, or use `most_recent` to choose the most recent one. If you want to match multiple AMIs, use the `aws_ami_ids` data source instead.

Also note that I added the `owners` field to your data source. This is [now](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pull/5576) [required](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/ami.html#owners) since [version `2.0.0`](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-february-27-2019) because otherwise this was very insecure as your data source could return any public image that uses that naming scheme.